# Generating a histogram from column values in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, histogram

Let's say I have a database column 'grade' like this:

```
|grade|
|    1|
|    2|
|    1|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
```

Is there a non-trivial way in SQL to generate a histogram like this?

```
|2,1,1,1,1,0|
```

where 2 means the grade 1 occurs twice, the 1s mean grades {2..5} occur once and 0 means grade 6 does not occur at all.

I don't mind if the histogram is one row per count.

If that matters, the database is SQL Server accessed by a perl CGI through unixODBC/FreeTDS.

**EDIT:** Thanks for your quick replies! It is okay if non-existing values (like grade 6 in the example above) do not occur as long as I can make out which histogram value belongs to which grade.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(grade) FROM table GROUP BY grade ORDER BY grade
```

Haven't verified it, but it should work.It will not, however, show count for 6s grade, since it's not present in the table at all...

Answer (score 21):

If there are a lot of data points, you can also [group ranges together](https://web.archive.org/web/20180205094300/https://www.wagonhq.com/sql-tutorial/creating-a-histogram-sql) like this:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(grade/5.00)*5 As Grade, 
       COUNT(*) AS [Grade Count]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FLOOR(Grade/5.00)*5
ORDER BY 1
```

Additionally, if you wanted to label the full range, you can get the floor and ceiling ahead of time with a CTE.

```sql
With GradeRanges As (
  SELECT FLOOR(Score/5.00)*5     As GradeFloor, 
         FLOOR(Score/5.00)*5 + 4 As GradeCeiling
  FROM TableName
)
SELECT GradeFloor,
       CONCAT(GradeFloor, ' to ', GradeCeiling) AS GradeRange,
       COUNT(*) AS [Grade Count]
FROM GradeRanges
GROUP BY GradeFloor, CONCAT(GradeFloor, ' to ', GradeCeiling)
ORDER BY GradeFloor
```

**Note**: In some SQL engines, you can `GROUP BY` an Ordinal Column Index, but with MS SQL, if you want it in the `SELECT` statement, you're going to need to group by it also, hence copying the Range into the Group Expression as well.

**Option 2**: You could use [case statements to selectively count values into arbitrary bins and then unpivot them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105218/1366033) to get a row by row count of included values

Comment: This is also valuable for continuous values - like values with decimal places such as an amount of money, or a group of values that represent a list of averages.

Answer (score 7):

Use a temp table to get your missing values:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(num int)
DECLARE @num int
SET @num = 0
WHILE @num < 10
BEGIN
  INSERT #tmp @num
  SET @num = @num + 1
END


SELECT t.num as [Grade], count(g.Grade) FROM gradeTable g
RIGHT JOIN #tmp t on g.Grade = t.num
GROUP by t.num
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Better: Generate your identity table via `select top 10 identity(int, 1, 1) as num into #tmp from sysobjects, sys.all_colums`

Answer (score 4):

Gamecat's use of DISTINCT seems a little odd to me, will have to try it out when I'm back in the office...

The way I would do it is similar though...

```
SELECT
    [table].grade        AS [grade],
    COUNT(*)             AS [occurances]
FROM
    [table]
GROUP BY
    [table].grade
ORDER BY
    [table].grade
```

To overcome the lack of data where there are 0 occurances, you can LEFT JOIN on to a table containing all valid grades.  The COUNT(*) will count NULLS, but COUNT(grade) won't count the NULLS.

```
DECLARE @grades TABLE (
   val INT
   )  

INSERT INTO @grades VALUES (1)  
INSERT INTO @grades VALUES (2)  
INSERT INTO @grades VALUES (3)  
INSERT INTO @grades VALUES (4)  
INSERT INTO @grades VALUES (5)  
INSERT INTO @grades VALUES (6)  

SELECT
    [grades].val         AS [grade],
    COUNT([table].grade) AS [occurances]
FROM
    @grades   AS [grades]
LEFT JOIN
    [table]
        ON [table].grade = [grades].val
GROUP BY
    [grades].val
ORDER BY
    [grades].val
```

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. And missed the group by. SQL to rusty error.

Answer (score 4):

According to Shlomo Priymak's article [How to Quickly Create a Histogram in MySQL](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2011/08/how-to-quickly-create-histogram-in.html), you can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT grade, 
       COUNT(*) AS 'Count',
       RPAD('', COUNT(*), '*') AS 'Bar' 
FROM grades 
GROUP BY grade
```

Which will produce the following table:

```
grade   Count   Bar
1       2       **
2       1       *
3       1       *
4       1       *
5       1       *
```

Comment: KyleMit, Thank you for cleaning up my answer but the edit introduced spurious backslashes, not sanctioned by the https://dev.MySQL.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html doc.
Maybe some SQL tool chains tolerate or require such syntax mangling?

Comment: The backslashes were in the original version of your answer https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25705553/edit/f5fbc075-a759-487a-b148-950c350a5cc3 - formatting them as code just made them visible in the rendered markdown

Answer (score 3):

```
select Grade, count(Grade)
from MyTable
group by Grade
```

Answer (score 0):

I am building on what Ilya Volodin did above, that should allow you to select a range of grade you want to group together in your result:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 100 -- Set max value
BEGIN
SELECT @cnt,COUNT(fe) FROM dbo.GEODATA_CB where fe >= @cnt-0.999 and fe <= @cnt+0.999 -- set tolerance
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1; -- set step
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FLOOR(grade/5.00)*5 As Grade_Lower, 
FLOOR(grade/5.00)*5+5 As Grade_Upper
       COUNT(*) AS [Grade Count]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FLOOR(Grade/5.00)*5, FLOOR(grade/5.00)*5+5
ORDER BY 1
```

Video tutorial if you like

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioc-NU4meu8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Group by ranges and consider empty ranges**

This is an extension to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41275222/895245 which also creates bins for the empty ranges with 0 entries in them:

```
select x, sum(cnt) from (
  select floor(x/5)*5 as x,
         count(*) as cnt
    from t
    group by 1
  union
  select *, 0 as cnt from generate_series(0, 15, 5)
)
group by x
```

Tested with:

```
create table t(x integer)
insert into t values (
  0,
  2,
  2,
  3,

  5,
  6,
  6,
  8,
  9,

  17,
)
```

Output:

```
0|4
5|5
10|0
15|1
```

The trick is to create a range of zeroes with `generate_series`, and then `sum` it up with the populated ranges. It doesn't alter the counts for populated ranges, but produces the 0 entry.

**Multiple range queries are generally faster than the `floor()` technique**

Although using `floor()` is convenient and self contained, it is likely going to be slower on most (?) implementations.

For example, I create a test database with 10m rows:

```
f="10m.sqlite"
rm -f "$f"
sqlite3 "$f" 'create table t(x integer)'
time sqlite3 "$f" 'insert into t select value as x from generate_series(0,9999999)'
time sqlite3 "$f" 'create index tx on t(x)'
```

Then, multiple queries with bins of size 1m:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
  sqlite3 10m.sqlite "select count(*) from t where x >= $i and x < $((i + 1000000))"
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

finishes in 0.45s. Doing floor however:

```
sqlite3 10m.sqlite <<EOF
select floor(x/1000000)*1000000 as x,
       count(*) as cnt
from t
group by 1
order by 1
EOF
```

takes 0.37 seconds.

My theory is that this is simply because of the overhead of the floor, division and multiplication, which the ranged version skips, and just goes through the B-tree index counting.

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04 SQLite 3.40.1, Lenovo ThinkPad P51, SSD: Samsung MZVLB512HAJQ-000L7 512GB SSD, 3 GB/s nominal speed.