# using sql count in a case statement

Tags: sql

I have a table and i need to present the output in the following fashion.

```
tb_a:

col1  |  reg_id | rsp_ind
```

Count of rows with rsp_ind = 0 as 'New' and 1 as 'Accepted'

The output should be

```
NEW | Accepted
9   | 10
```

I tried using the following query.

```
select 
  case when rsp_ind = 0 then count(reg_id)end as 'New',
  case when rsp_ind = 1 then count(reg_id)end as 'Accepted'
from tb_a
```

and i m getting output as

```
NEW | Accepted
NULL| 10
9   | NULL
```

Could someone help to me tweak the query to achieve the output.
Note : I cannot add a sum surrounding this. Its part of a bigger program and so i cannot add a super-query to this.

Comment: u cant add a sum but can u change the query? or make this a subquery?

Comment: i can add a subquery instead of case statement. But not a super query above this... 
Adding a subquery obviously comes with performance hit...

Comment: I see.. then maybe you can add this subquery to your join clause instead of making an inline subquery..is that possible in ur code?

Comment: Please show your whole query, in particular your `GROUP BY` clause! Also, what DBMS and version--Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server 2008, what?

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rsp_ind = 0 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "New",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN rsp_ind = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "Accepted"
from tb_a
```

You can see the output for this request [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84442/1)

Comment: this wouldnt go with what the OP asks for

Comment: @JafarKofahi feel free to explain yourself ! It seems to me that it's exactly what he's loooking for...

Comment: in the OP he said "Note : I cannot add a sum surrounding this. Its "

Comment: Tell me where do you see a sum ?

Comment: I think he meant that he cant use any aggregate functions since its a part of a bigger query coz he cant add a `group by`

Comment: I can add a group by to the select.

Comment: The output is same as the current one, but instead of null, it gives 0s... I need to merge the rows to a single one...

Comment: @Raghav take a look at my SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 23):

Depending on you flavor of SQL, you can also [imply the else statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123668/31340) in your aggregate counts.

For example, here's a simple table `Grades`:

```
| Letters |
|---------|
| A       |
| A       |
| B       |
| C       |
```

We can test out each Aggregate counter syntax like this ([**Interactive Demo in SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/32254)):

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Letter = 'A' THEN 1 END)           AS [Count - End],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Letter = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Count - Else Null],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Letter = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS [Count - Else Zero],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Letter = 'A' THEN 1 END)             AS [Sum - End],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Letter = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)   AS [Sum - Else Null],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Letter = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)      AS [Sum - Else Zero]
FROM Grades
```

And here are the results ([unpivoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19056083/1366033) for readability):

```
|    Description    | Counts |
|-------------------|--------|
| Count - End       |    2   |
| Count - Else Null |    2   |
| Count - Else Zero |    4   | *Note: Will include count of zero values
| Sum - End         |    2   |
| Sum - Else Null   |    2   |
| Sum - Else Zero   |    2   |
```

Which lines up with the docs for [Aggregate Functions in SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Docs for [**`COUNT`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> `COUNT(*)` - returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL values and duplicates.
>   `COUNT(ALL expression)` - evaluates expression for each row in a group, and returns the number of nonnull values.
>   `COUNT(DISTINCT expression)` - evaluates expression for each row in a group, and returns the number of unique, nonnull values.

Docs for [**`SUM`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> `ALL` - Applies the aggregate function to all values. ALL is the default.
>   `DISTINCT` - Specifies that SUM return the sum of unique values.

Answer (score 15):

Close... try:

```
select 
   Sum(case when rsp_ind = 0 then 1 Else 0 End) as 'New',
   Sum(case when rsp_ind = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Accepted'
from tb_a
```

Comment: this wouldnt go with what the OP asks for

Comment: The OP says that this gives him two rows instead of one.

Comment: typo only - left off one closing parentheses.  Surprised it even worked.

Comment: I'm sure he figured out the parenthesis and I'm sure that its lack is not what made two rows appear instead of one.

Comment: "It's not what you don't know that'll hurt you, it's what you do know that ain't so."

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting two rows instead of one is that you are grouping by `rsp_ind` in the outer query (which you did not, to my disappointment, share with us). There is nothing you can do to force one row instead of two without dealing with that `GROUP BY` item.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to group the results based on a column and take the count based on the same, you can run the query as :

```
$sql = "SELECT COLUMNNAME,

COUNT(CASE WHEN COLUMNNAME IN ('YOURCONDITION') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'New',

COUNT(CASE WHEN COLUMNNAME IN ('YOURCONDITION') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'ACCPTED'

FROM TABLENAME

GROUP BY COLUMNANME";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #CountMe (Col1 char(1));

INSERT INTO #CountMe VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO #CountMe VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO #CountMe VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO #CountMe VALUES ('B');

SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS CountWithoutElse,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CountWithElseNull,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountWithElseZero
FROM #CountMe;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(rsp_ind = 0) as `New`,
       sum(rsp_ind = 1) as `Accepted` 
from tb_a
```

Comment: An important detail given the OP didn't say what DBMS this is for.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I solved it

```
SELECT `smart_projects`.project_id, `smart_projects`.business_id, `smart_projects`.title,
 `page_pages`.`funnel_id` as `funnel_id`, count(distinct(page_pages.page_id) )as page_count, count(distinct (CASE WHEN page_pages.funnel_id != 0 then  page_pages.funnel_id ELSE NULL END ) ) as funnel_count
FROM `smart_projects`
LEFT JOIN `page_pages` ON `smart_projects`.`project_id` = `page_pages`.`project_id`
WHERE  smart_projects.status !=  0 
AND `smart_projects`.`business_id` = 'cd9412774edb11e9'
GROUP BY `smart_projects`.`project_id`
ORDER BY `title` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this solution, as I came here while searching for how to classify and count data in one statement. Using a double select you can get a query that has the count and the 'classification' in the result. Hope someone finds this useful.

```
SELECT A, COUNT(A) AS Count FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN [Col1] = 'Option1' OR [Col1] = 'Option2'
                THEN 'Classification 1'
                 
                WHEN [Col1] = 'Option3' OR 'Option4' 
                THEN 'Classification 2'
    
                WHEN [Col1] = 'Option4' 
                THEN 'Classification 3'
            END As A
          FROM [Table1] 
          ) AS G
    GROUP BY A
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN user_type = 'Admin' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS mid_dead_count
FROM
    users
WHERE
    DATE = '2022-01-02';
```