# Unpivot with column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unpivot

I have a table `StudentMarks` with columns `Name, Maths, Science, English`.
Data is like

```
Name,  Maths, Science, English  
Tilak, 90,    40,      60  
Raj,   30,    20,      10
```

I want to get it arranged like the following:

```
Name,  Subject,  Marks
Tilak, Maths,    90
Tilak, Science,  40
Tilak, English,  60
```

With [unpivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) I am able to get Name, Marks properly, but not able to get the column name in the source table to the `Subject` column in the desired result set.

How can I achieve this?

I have so far reached the following query (to get Name, Marks)

```
select Name, Marks from studentmarks
Unpivot
(
  Marks for details in (Maths, Science, English)

) as UnPvt
```

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Your query is very close. You should be able to use the following which includes the `subject` in the final select list:

```
select u.name, u.subject, u.marks
from student s
unpivot
(
  marks
  for subject in (Maths, Science, English)
) u;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3771e/1)

Comment: @bluefeet Is there a way such that you don't need to specify the names (Maths, Science, English)? I am doing this operation to many tables, all with the same structure but with different column names.

Comment: @LBogaardt No, you need to explicitly define the columns to include.

Comment: @LBogaardt Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18026337/426671), you could use dynamic sql to unpivot without specifying the column names.

Answer (score 11):

You may also try standard sql un-pivoting method by using a sequence of logic with the following code..
The following code has 3 steps:

1. create multiple copies for each row using cross join (also creating subject column in this case)
2. create column "marks" and fill in relevant values using case expression ( ex: if subject is science then pick value from science column)
3. remove any null combinations ( if exists, table expression can be fully avoided if there are strictly no null values in base table)

   ```
    select *
    from 
    (
       select name, subject,
       case subject
       when 'Maths' then maths
       when 'Science' then science
       when 'English' then english
       end as Marks
   from studentmarks
   Cross Join (values('Maths'),('Science'),('English')) AS Subjct(Subject)
   )as D
   where marks is not null;
   ```

Comment: This also works with any RDBMS! VALUES, when not available, can be replaced by a subquery with SELECT ... UNION  ... SELECT ... Wondering about the performance of that CROSS JOIN though...

Answer (score 6):

Another way around using cross join would be to specify column names inside cross join

```
select name, Subject, Marks 
from studentmarks
Cross Apply (
    values (Maths,'Maths'),(Science,'Science'),(English,'English')
) un(Marks, Subject)
where marks is not null;
```