# How to Display Columns as Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rows

I've a result set in SQL Server as follows:

```
PM    SPM   QA
714   NULL  NULL
```

I want to get a Result Set as follows:

```
Members
714 
NULL    
NULL
```

How to do This?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unpivot with column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov It's a remote database and PIVOT and UNPIVOT requires the compatibility level of the database to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select PM Members From tbl
union all
select SPM From tbl
union all
select QA From tbl
```