# Sql Query to convert from columns to rows

Tags: sql-server

I am having very large table 151 columns - each column represents one store (150 stores * 1 column) plus one date column.

```
Date         Store001       Store002      Store003      Store004 ................... Store150
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
01/01/14     12560          8546           7468          10154                        16845

31/10/14     13978          7584           8456          13458                        25458
```

I need the results as follows:

```
Date         Store#        Amount
-----------------------------------
01/01/14     Store001      12560
01/01/14     Store002      8546
01/01/14     Store003      7468
01/01/14     Store004      10154
etc.,
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unpivot with column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table yourtable([Date]  date,Store001 int ,Store002 int)
insert into yourtable ([Date],Store001,Store002)
values
(GETDATE(),1243,546),
(GETDATE(),4545,798),
(GETDATE(),5687,456),
(GETDATE(),0756,685)
```

**Simple Query**

```
   ;WITH CTE
AS
  (
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT [Date],Store001,Store002 FROM yourtable) T
  UNPIVOT ( Value FOR N IN (Store001,Store002))P
  )
 SELECT [Date],N as Store#,SUM(Value) as Amount
 FROM CTE
 GROUP BY [Date],N
```

**Dynamic SQL**

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max) 
select @cols = coalesce(@cols+N',', N'') + quotename(c.name) from syscolumns c
inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = 'u'
where o.name = 'yourtable' and c.name not in ('Date') order by c.colid
select @cols
declare @query nvarchar(max) 

select @query = N'
 ;WITH CTE
AS
  (
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT [Date], ' + @cols + '
FROM yourtable) T
  UNPIVOT ( Value FOR N IN (' + @cols + '))P
  )
 SELECT [Date],N as Store#,SUM(Value) as Amount
 FROM CTE
 GROUP BY [Date],N
'
print @query 
exec sp_executesql @query
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Date         Store#     Amount
2014-11-02  Store001    12231
2014-11-02  Store002    2485
```

Comment: Excellent Mr Ganesh. I just registered and never expected such quick response.

Comment: @MohanYGK Your welcome if u think this is helpful then mark it as answer

Comment: We are implementing AX 2012 for 150 retail outlets covering production, inventory, retail management, payroll, treasury etc., I am looking for a IT manager position in my company. I don't know your background and your interests, but if you are interested, let me know.

Comment: Going back to the query, as an example, I mentioned as store001, store002. But what we are doing is based on city name, we are giving the store code. For example, in Riyadh, we are defining store code as RYD01, RYD02.... but if in Jeddah, we are defining JED01, JED02 etc., we are having our presence in 27 stores. In such case, dynamic query may not work. Any other way to address this issue.

Comment: @MohanYGK Please Edit Your question with your sample data and what you want to say

Comment: @Dyanmic SQL only for getting desire columns names from `syscolumns` all system columns

Comment: @MohanYGK  I think you need to normalize your Table. Don't store values like this `RYD01, RYD02`....etc....

Comment: @MohanYGK Then its time change or Migrate (Totally your decision)

Comment: are you interested to join our Group in KSA (Riyadh) as IT Manager

Comment: We are implementing AX 2012

Comment: @MohanYGK Thanks for Your appreciation.I would like to work.But I am from Mumbai.Your company is in Saudi Arabia :O

Comment: We will provide you the employment contract and you can relocate to Riyadh.

Comment: @MohanYGK Can I work Part time for your company from India ??

Comment: No boss. It is full time job. We are implementing AX 2012 for massive operations. If any of your friends looking for the abroad opportunity as IT manager, please let me know.

Comment: Yes Sir, if there is any one i will let you know

Comment: I would like to upload data from excel to sql server using VB code. Do you have any code

Comment: @MohanYGK vb.net or vb 6.0 ??

Comment: any thing is OK. I am interested in the results

Comment: Regarding uploading data from excel to SQL server by using Excel VB

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/ check this it will convert your excel sheet into table

Comment: Sir Ji, this will not insert additional rows into SQL table. In other words, I need to insert the rows into SQL table

Comment: @MohanYGK mail your excel to me gdevlekar[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: Boss check your email