# SQL change columns to row but keep one column as the column before all the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Example

```
Team | Person1 | Person2 | Person3
```

change to

```
Team | Person 1
Team | Person 2
Team | Person 3
```

I wasn't sure how to describe exactly what it was that I wanted to do, sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: You're looking for `UNPIVOT` plenty of good examples available.  Here's one: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name) question should show you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might try (besides the the solution user @GoatCO mentioned in the comments) the following query:

```
SELECT Team, [Person 1] As Person_Column
FROM _table
UNION ALL
SELECT Team, [Person 2] As Person_Column
FROM _table
UNION ALL
SELECT Team, [Person 3] As Person_Column
FROM _table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNPIVOT`

For table dbo.Teams, using your example:

```
SELECT Team, Person
FROM
(
  SELECT Team, Person1, Person2, Person3
  FROM dbo.Teams
) as cp
UNPIVOT
(
  Person FOR Persons IN (Person1, Person2, Person3)
) AS up;
```

While using `UNIONs` works, it does not scale well, costing a lot more for each additional column you need to transpose.

NOTE: This is basically a clone of the solution to a near identical question at [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3000/use-sql-servers-unpivot-operator-to-help-normalize-output/) article, provided in the initial question comments by user @Goat CO. See the link for additional information and expansion on this solution.