# How to convert horizontal row into vertical SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Query:

```
Select 
    COUNT(aciklama)as Permitted,   
    (Select COUNT(aciklama) 
     from Uyari 
     where Aciklama like '%Blocked%') as Blocked 
From 
    Uyari 
where 
    Aciklama like '%Permitted%'
```

Output:

```
Permitted     Blocked
----------------------
    74         9194
```

I want result like this:

```
Permitted   ...      74
Blocked    ...     9194
```

Could any one help?

Comment: what database server do you use? version?

Comment: This is an "unpivot" action, which is answered in a number of other questions throughout stack overflow.

Comment: MrSimpleMind Sorry, SQL Server 2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unpivot with column name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Comment: Tab Alleman I tried a lot but I din not make it, could you please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using `union all`

```
select 'Permitted' action, COUNT(aciklama) as result
from Uyari 
where Aciklama like '%Permitted%'
union all
select 'Blocked' action, COUNT(aciklama)   
from Uyari 
where Aciklama like '%Blocked%'
```