# How to combine multiple columns into one column and its data into another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I looked around first before posting this and found a lot of questions like this but not the solution I was looking for, this question is different...

I was tasked to normalize an existing database and now I am stuck when writing a view thats to be transparent to the existing database, so I wrote this...

```
SELECT 
    Customer.CustomerID, CustomerContact.CustomerContactID,
    CustomerPhone.Phone AS "1",
    CustomerPhone.Work AS "2",
    CustomerPhone.Mobile AS "3",
    CustomerPhone.Fax AS "4",
    CustomerPhone.Other AS "5", 
    CustomerSpouse.Spouse AS "6", 
    CustomerSpouse.SpouseMobile AS "7"
FROM
    [Customer] 
INNER JOIN 
    CustomerContact ON Customer.CustomerID = CustomerContact.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN 
    CustomerPhone ON CustomerContact.CustomerContactID = CustomerPhone.CustomerContactID 
INNER JOIN 
    CustomerSpouse ON CustomerContact.CustomerContactID = CustomerSpouse.CustomerContactID
```

So I made a mistake with the normalization, in the existing database, the CustomerPhone table looks like this

[image: Existing database table]

Now I have no idea how to put all the columns into a new column called `PhoneType` and show the phone number in another column called `PhoneNumber`.

I would rather not have to go back and change the tables from what I already have done, that is a last resort.

I apologize if how I explained it sounds confusing, if it does then please let me know and i'll make an edit and try to explain it better.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is the diagram of the tables

[image: Diagram]

Here is what I have being returned with the query that I wrote

[image: What is being returned with my query]

So I need every column that has an integer for a header to be placed in a column called PhoneType and its corresponding phone number into a column called PhoneNumber.

What I need to do with my query is making it return this.

```
PhoneType | PhoneNumber
1         | 123-4567
2         | 234-5678
3         | 345-6789
```

Comment: How can a "CustomerPhone" table not have a customer identifier?

Comment: It does have one, its the CustomerID from another table. I just didn't add it to the screenshot because, as far as I know, doesn't pertain to my problem. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Each customer has up to 7 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `unpivot` (see also [this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name):

```
create table phones_wide (customerid int, "1" varchar(20), "2" varchar(20), "3" varchar(20), "4" varchar(20), "5" varchar(20), "6" varchar(20), "7" varchar(20));
insert into phones_wide values (1234, '123-4342', '223-4342', '323-4342', '423-4342', '523-4342', '623-4342', '723-4342')

select PhoneType, PhoneNumber
from phones_wide
unpivot
(
  PhoneNumber
  for PhoneType in ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
) u;

drop table phones_wide
```

Output:

```
PhoneType   PhoneNumber
1   123-4342
2   223-4342
3   323-4342
4   423-4342
5   523-4342
6   623-4342
7   723-4342
```

Comment: I tried modifying what you suggested, and I took a look at the link you provided, this would work if my table looked like the pic that I attached. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of your 'normalized' table?

Comment: Sure, its a combination of 4 tables altogether, I tried logging into SQLFiddle, but it wouldn't let me. One sec..

Comment: What error are you getting? I've added an example table into my code, and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Not getting any errors now. I seen why I was getting errors, I needed to put my select statement as a sub query and give it an alias. Thanks for getting this straightened out for me I appreciate it.