# SQL : Split one row into two rows depending on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am sorry if this is duplicate. Please point me to correct question. I am using SQL SERVER 2008. I am using below query since I need to get data from 3 tables.

```
SELECT qc.FileID as [FileID],    
qc.QID1 as [QID1],    
xqs.SID1 as [SID1],   
xqc.CID1 as [CID1],  
xqs.Comments as [SComments],  
xqc.Comments as [CComments]  
FROM QCTable(nolock) qc  
JOIN QCSectionTable (nolock) xqs ON qc.QCID = xqs.QCID  
LEFT JOIN QCChargeTable (nolock) xqc ON xqc.QCXrefID = xqs.QCXrefID
```

For above I am getting this like
FieID1 SID1 SID1 CID1 SComments CComments

I have a row like below

```
FileID1  QID1 SID1 CID1 SComments  CComments
```

I need to split above row as

```
FileID1 QID1 SID1 null SComments
FileID1 QID1 SID1 CID1 CComments
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like you might be able to use [unpivot.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)    Here's an [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Comment: A bit off topic but why the nolocks? Do you know all the "benefits"...err pitfalls of that particular query hint? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @Sean : I am using nolock in my real query. This is just sample query.

Comment: Not sure I follow...you should read that article and understand the evils of that hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 
     qc.FileID AS [FileID1]
    ,qc.QID1 AS [QID1]
    ,xqs.SID1 AS [SID1]
    ,NULL AS [CID1]    --assigning default value as null
    ,xqs.Comments AS [SComments]
FROM QCTable(NOLOCK) qc
JOIN QCSectionTable(NOLOCK) xqs ON qc.QCID = xqs.QCID
LEFT JOIN QCChargeTable(NOLOCK) xqc ON xqc.QCXrefID = xqs.QCXrefID

UNION ALL

SELECT 
     qc.FileID AS [FileID1]
    ,qc.QID1 AS [QID1]
    ,xqs.SID1 AS [SID1]
    ,xqc.CID1 AS [CID1]
    ,xqc.Comments AS [CComments]
FROM QCTable(NOLOCK) qc
JOIN QCSectionTable(NOLOCK) xqs ON qc.QCID = xqs.QCID
LEFT JOIN QCChargeTable(NOLOCK) xqc ON xqc.QCXrefID = xqs.QCXrefID
```

Comment: I did what you said but in my second select query I used INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN. I am marking this as answer.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is `union all`:

```
select FileID1, QID1, SID1, null as cId1, SComments
from table t
union all
select  FileID1, QID1, SID1, cId1, CComments
from table t;
```

If you have a large amount of data, it can be a bit faster to do this using `cross apply` or a `cross join`:

```
select v.*
from table t cross apply
     (values (FileID1, QID1, SID1, null, SComments),
             (FileID1, QID1, SID1, cId1, CComments)
     ) v(FileID1, QID1, SID1, cId1, CComments);
```

The advantage is that this would scan the table only once.

Comment: I updated my question and more info about my requirement. Thanks

Comment: Thanks I used UNION ALL

Comment: @Ziggler . . . Given that your table has changed into a query, I think you would get better performance with `cross apply`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FileID1, QID1, DID1, null, SComments
FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT FileID1, QID1, SID1, CID1, CComments
FROM table
```

Comment: I updated my question and more info about my requirement. Thanks

Comment: Thanks I used UNION ALL.