# SQL Query for field name, field type, and field value

Tags: sql, field-names

Let's say I have a table like the one below

```
pp_refno   pp_rectype   _pp_account  pp_empid   pp_dept
---------------------------------------------------------
90221      contractor    061509864   C00001121  1111000139
```

Is there a query that could be written such that the data is returned in this format?

```
field_name          field_type     field_value
---------------------------------------------------------
pp_refno            int             90221
pp_rectype          char            contractor
pp_account          char            061509864
pp_empid            char            C00001121 
pp_dept             char            1111000139
```

Comment: Not in "standard SQL", however it's probably possible if you narrow it down to a specific database system dialect.

Comment: the query varies depending on the database you are using. Please specify  your database.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible by using the information schema of the database you are using. You do however have to add 1 column to be able to use this for multiple rows:

```
field_name          field_type     field_value        pp_refno
--------------------------------------------------------------
pp_refno            int             90221             90221
pp_rectype          char            contractor        90221
pp_account          char            061509864         90221
pp_empid            char            C00001121         90221
pp_dept             char            1111000139        90221
```

This way you can identify multiple records.

Also you will have to write or generate a specific query for each table, which can be large and slow due to the way the data works.

If you are just retrieving single rows, you could also use a stored procedure to list your data in the given fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UNPIVOT function of SQL query to achieve this behavior. Below link gives you more idea with the similar example.

[Example Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

To read the column type, you need to join the sys tables and get the column types

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
 TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName' AND 
 COLUMN_NAME = 'yourColumnName'
```

Once you have the unpivot table alias, you should be able to join the same with SCHEMA.columns table and get your logic implemented