# SQL Columns to List

Tags: t-sql, unpivot

I have the following table contents:-

[image: Table Structure]

And I need to produce the following output:-

P1 C1 
P1 C3 
P2 C1 
P2 C4 
P3 C2 
P3 C3 
P3 C4

How can I create that list from my table?

Thanks

P

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I have tried to use Unpivot but I am quite unfamiliar with it. I think its the way I need to go but I don't know how to use it properly

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name

Comment: I can get the Unpivot syntax, I'm just having trouble applying it to my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [UnPivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the desired result

```
    DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(Attribute VARCHAR(10) , C1 VARCHAR(10), C2 VARCHAR(10), C3 VARCHAR(10), C4 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
('P1','X', NULL,'X',NULL), ('P2','X',NULL,NULL,'X'),('P3',NULL,'X','X','X')

SELECT * FROM @MyTable

SELECT uPivot.Attribute, uPivot.Quatr, uPivot.IsMarked
FROM @MyTable Tab1
UNPIVOT
        (
          IsMarked
          for Quatr in (C1, C2, C3, C4)
        ) uPivot;
```

[SQL FIDDLER EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1698/89)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

This should work based off the information provided.

```
select u.P, -- whatever the column containing p1, p2, etc is called
u.C,
u.Contents -- what is stored in each cell
from xtable
unpivot
(
  Contents
  for C in (c1, c2, c3)
) u
where u.Contents like 'x'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d908/1/0

I pretty much slightly modified the example given in what Ako linked in the comments.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I implemented in the end

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColName TABLE (Name VARCHAR(500))
DECLARE @ColCSV VARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO  @ColName 
SELECT
    Column_Name
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    Table_Name = 'SMC_PatientCondition'
    AND Column_Name NOT IN 
        ('ReportingCode',
        'P_PatientId',
        'P_SysId',
        'Condition')

SET @ColCSV = (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + Name FROM @ColName FOR XML PATH ('')),2,2000) AS CSV)

SET @SQL =
('
SELECT
    P_SysID,
    Conditions
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            P_SysId,
            RIGHT(Conditions, LEN(Conditions)-2) Conditions,
            HasCondition
        FROM
            SMC_PatientCondition
        UNPIVOT
        (
            HasCondition FOR Conditions IN ('+ @ColCSV +')
        )Con
    ) UserConditions
WHERE
    HasCondition = ''Yes''
')

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```