# Column to rows, rows to rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like this

```
      id  |    vname1    |   vname2 | vname3     
      1   |     vala     |   valb   | valc
```

I want this to convert like this

```
     id | vname  | vals 
     1  | vname1 | vala
     1  | vname2 | valb
     1  | vname3 | valc
```

I thought about pivoting but here I think is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `UNION ALL`, with one `SELECT` for each vname column:

```
select id, 'vname1' as vname, vname1 as vals from tablename
union all
select id, 'vname2' as vname, vname2 as vals from tablename
union all
select id, 'vname3' as vname, vname3 as vals from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **UNPIVOT** function to convert the columns into rows:

**Sample Example:**

```
select Id,
  indicatorname,
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  indicatorvalue
  for indicatorname in (Indicator1, Indicator2, Indicator3)
) unpiv;
```

Link for reference: [UnPivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)