# Case statement in a un pivot scenario sql

Tags: sql, case, unpivot

I'm trying to un pivot a query set as below

```
Member ID   N1code  N2code  N3code  Name 
1234        234     567     878     ted 
23344       4242    23232           Mike
```

I want a case statement of some kind that helps show the type after unpivoting

```
MemberID Codes  Name    Type 
1234     234    ted     N1
1234     567    ted     N2
1234     878    ted     N3
23344    4242   Mike    N1
23344   23232   Mike    N2
```

Comment: What flavor and version of SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpivot with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Answer (score 0):

in PostgreSQL you could turn the columns to an array and then unnest (explode):

```
select MemberID, unnest(array[N1code, N2code, N3code]) as Codes, Name
from table
```

Comment: `Type` is coming from the `N(x)code` column names, with only the first 2 characters

Comment: i edited it out because it should be a comment on the question and not in the answer

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, it's just a simple `UNPIVOT`. There's no need for the `CASE` statement, as the original column name comes back in the `UNPIVOT`. We're able to just pull the left 2 characters from the original column name. If you wanted it to be something other than a derivative of the column name, you would have to use a `CASE`.

Look at the outermost select to see where those selected columns are coming from.

```
SELECT unpiv.MemberID, unpiv.Name, unpiv.theCode, left(codes,2) AS theType
FROM
(
  SELECT MemberID, Name, N1Code, N2Code, N3Code
  FROM t1
) AS src
UNPIVOT 
(
  theCode FOR codes IN (N1Code, N2Code, N3Code)
) AS unpiv;
```

For MySQL 5.x and lower, you can use a `CROSS JOIN` and a couple of `CASE` statements.

```
SELECT t1.MemberID, t1.Name
    , CASE cj.colName
        WHEN 'N1Code' then t1.N1Code
        WHEN 'N2Code' then t1.N2Code
        WHEN 'N3Code' then t1.N3Code
      END AS theCode
    , CASE cj.colName
        WHEN 'N1Code' then 'N1'
        WHEN 'N2Code' then 'N2'
        WHEN 'N3Code' then 'N3'
      END AS theType
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT 'N1Code' AS colName
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N2Code'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N3Code'
) cj
```

Comment: Thank you ! i did resolve it with the Cross apply function.