# get the positon of a column where value exists while unpivoting the table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I am trying to get the column position of a value while doing an unpivot on the columns col2, col3, col4 in SQL server

```
df1
col1     col2     col3     col4     
1        AAA      BBB
2        ABC      CCC      DDD

result
col1     [All]     [position]
1        AAA        1
1        BBB        2
2        ABC        1
2        CCC        2
2        DDD        3
```

I am able to unpivot the table by using the following

```
SELECT a.col1, a.[all]
from df1 as t
UNPIVOT
(
[all] for col_nm in (
    col2, col3, col4
) as a
```

Comment: how did you get 3 on col1 ? please provide your logic too

Comment: @Avi, sorry that was a typo. I am not sure what you mean by logic but I have provided code on how I am Unpivoting the table

Comment: try reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name) it might help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just need to know which column it's from, i think you can simply include the col_nm into your select statement:

```
SELECT a.col1
      ,a.[all]
      ,a.col_nm
FROM   df1 AS t UNPIVOT([all] FOR col_nm IN(col2, col3, col4)) AS a;
```

if you need to know the column index number - then it should be easy based on above - perhaps do a switch-case check for the column name; or,

if this is a physical or temp table, you can join back with sys.tables and sys.columns to find the column index (columnId) based on the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using `row_number()`

```
SELECT a.col1, a.[all],row_number() over(partition by a.col1 order by a.[all]) as position
from df1 as t
UNPIVOT
(
[all] for col_nm in (
    col2, col3, col4
) as a
```

Comment: this does not seem to work - when using OrderBy the row_number() might not give you the correct column index...

Comment: @Rex, you better give it a try and show me that it won't work

Comment: ok, i did a try now, and confirmed it does not work - you can try your query after tweaking the first value "AAA" to be "ZZZ", you will see the column number becomes 3, because the order-by made it the last!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from (

select col1,1 as position , col2  as [All] from [Table] 
Union
select col1,2 as position, col3  as [All] from [Table] 
Union
select col1,3 as position, col4  as [All] from [Table] )
where [all] is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT df1.col1, dff.*     
FROM df1 as df CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (col2, 1), (col3, 2), (col4, 3) ) dff([All], [Position])
WHERE dff.[All] IS NOT NULL;
```