# convert rows to column using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have fix column and rows in my result. I want to convert the rows into columns.

I have checked but in pivoting we can transpose only single column into rows.

```
SELECT   MoveType,
         SUM(IsHazardous) AS IsHazardous,
         SUM(IsReefer) AS IsReefer,
         SUM (IsOOG) AS IsOOG
FROM     (SELECT qce.MoveType,
                 (CASE WHEN qce.IsHazardous='YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsHazardous,
                 (CASE WHEN qce.IsReefer='YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsReefer,
                 (CASE WHEN qce.IsOOG='YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsOOG
          FROM   qbtCallEquipmentExecution AS qcee
            INNER JOIN qbtCallEquipment qce ON
                 qce.ID=qcee.CallEquipmentID
            AND  qce.IsActive=1
          WHERE  qce.CallID=1169
          AND qcee.IsActive=1) AS A
GROUP BY MoveType
```

how to pivot this query .

Actual output:

```
MoveType                                        IsHazardous IsReefer    IsOOG
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ---
DSCR                                               0           0           0
LOAD                                               0           0           0
SHFT                                               0           0           0
```

Expected Output:

```
MoveType                                         DSCR       LOAD         SHFT
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ---
IsHazardous                                        0           0           0
IsReefer                                           0           0           0
IsOOG                                              0           0           0
```

Comment: Hi have you take look at UNPIVOT functionnality ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have tried it. It is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a known list of MoveType data then you can use the below query. If not, this will be a dynamic pivot/unpivot

<kbd>**[demo link](https://rextester.com/CZXH90480)**</kbd>

```
;with t as 
(
    SELECT   MoveType,
         SUM(IsHazardous) AS IsHazardous,
         SUM(IsReefer) AS IsReefer,
         SUM (IsOOG) AS IsOOG
FROM     (SELECT qce.MoveType,
                 (CASE WHEN qce.IsHazardous='YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsHazardous,
                 (CASE WHEN qce.IsReefer='YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsReefer,
                 (CASE WHEN qce.IsOOG='YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsOOG
          FROM   qbtCallEquipmentExecution AS qcee
            INNER JOIN qbtCallEquipment qce ON
                 qce.ID=qcee.CallEquipmentID
            AND  qce.IsActive=1
          WHERE  qce.CallID=1169
          AND qcee.IsActive=1) AS A
GROUP BY MoveType
)

select v as MoveType,DSCR,LOAD,SHFT 
from 
    (
        select * from t

    ) s
unpivot
    (
        data for v in (IsHazardous,IsReefer, IsOOG)
    )u
pivot 
    (
        sum(data) for MoveType in (DSCR,LOAD,SHFT)
    )p
```