# Convert row values as columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Table:

```
CompanyID   Lead   LeadManager
------------------------------
    1          2         3
```

Required output:

```
CompanyID   Role          RoleID
--------------------------------
   1        Lead            2
   1        Leadmanager     3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19055902/2029983)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` to *unpivot* your dataset. This is a standard solution that works across most (if not all) RDBMS:

```
select companyID, 'Lead' role, Lead from mytable
union all select companyID, 'LeadManager', LeadManager from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to unpivot the data:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.CompanyId, 'Lead', t.Lead),
             (t.CompanyId, 'LeadManager', t.LeadManager)
     ) v(CompanyId, Role, RoleId);
```

The advantage to this approach is that it scans the original table only once.  This can be particular helpful when the "table" is a complex query.