# Unpivot Table for Multiple Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a problem in Unpivot the table.

My table structure is

```
Code     Level1Name Level1Email Level2Name Level2Email Level3Name Level3 Email
1         aa        aa@b.com     bb          bb@b.com     cc        cc@c.com
```

I need to convert this columns into Rows and need output like below

```
Code  Info    Level1       Level2        Level3 
1     Name     aa           bb            cc
1     Email    aa@b.com    bb@b.com       cc@c.com
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19055902/2029983). What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work? If you don't understand the syntax, what about it don't you understand?

Comment: I used this code for the above scenario . It works for one Level ,but when i tried this for another level it not work. And the name want to be same for the 2 levels       select code,Info,Level1 from table
Unpivot
(
  Level 1 for Info in (Level1Name,Level1Email)
UNION
) as UnPvt                                            select code,Info,Level2 from table
Unpivot
(
  Level 2 for Info in (Level2Name,Level2Email)

) as UnPvt 1

Comment: Put your attempts in the question, not the comments. Use the [edit] feature.

Comment: Can u help me with this @Larnu

Comment: With using the [edit] feature? Click the hyperlink, and then put your attempt in there, using the copy and paste feature, inside a code fence (`\`\`\``).

Comment: Perhaps `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `apply`

```
select t.code, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('Name', t.Level1Name, t.Level2Name, t.Level1Name, Level3Name),
             ('Email', t.Level1Email, t.Level1Email, t.Level2Email, Level3Email)
     ) v(info, level1, level2, level3);
```