# Dynamic Select Query based on Query Column | SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

May I ask on how do we execute Dynamic Select Query?

Basically what I want to achieve is a dynamic select that can SELECT a query based on a dynamic column, and that dynamic column is existing in a table.

Example Table

```
Table Name: AppleBox
Table Columns: Apple101, Apple102, Apple103
Table Row: 
Apple101 = 1,2,3,4,5
Apple102 = 1,2,
Apple103 = 1
```

Supposed that I would run a query based on the example

```
SELECT apple+'$applecode' FROM AppleBox
```

with **$applecode** being from an external source, and **$applecode** = 101, and my expected query would be.

```
SELECT apple101 FROM AppleBox
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MS SQL Server, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should have such columns in a table.  Instead, you should have another table that has separate rows for each value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what if I'm stuck with that format and I do not have a way/ not allowed to modify the table, would this be possible?

Comment: @Akina thank you, ill look into Dynamic SQL

Comment: I agree with what's been said here, the problem appears to be the design; fix that and likely the problem you have does not exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpivot with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Comment: `and I do not have a way/ not allowed to modify the table` You cannot fix an issue if you are not allowed to make changes. Drop this project and move on to another client/project

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AppleBox](
    [Apple101] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Apple102] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Apple103] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[AppleBox] ([Apple101], [Apple102], [Apple103]) VALUES (N'1,2', N'1', N'1')
INSERT [dbo].[AppleBox] ([Apple101], [Apple102], [Apple103]) VALUES (N'3,4,5', N'1,2,', N'2')
INSERT [dbo].[AppleBox] ([Apple101], [Apple102], [Apple103]) VALUES (N'1,2,3,4,', N'1,2,3', N'3')
INSERT [dbo].[AppleBox] ([Apple101], [Apple102], [Apple103]) VALUES (N'1,2,3,4,5', N'1', N'4')


GO


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @exparam NVARCHAR(50)

SET @exparam='101'

SET @query='SELECT Apple'+@exparam+' FROM dbo.AppleBox'

EXECUTE sp_executesql  @query
```

Comment: What if Apple column will be expanded, is there a way for this to make it into a dynamic sql?

Comment: I didn't get your question. this @exparam will be your external parameter. it can be upto 123456789..... (n digits) as we have taken as nvarchar(50) length

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when $applecode = 101 then apple101
             when $applecode = 102 then apple102
             when $applecode = 103 then apple103
        end) as apple
from t;
```

You would only need dynamic SQL (in this case) if your query could return a variable number of columns or if you wanted to set the name of the column.  Neither seems important.

Comment: would there be a way for this? im worried because we might keep on expanding the SQL if there's more apple column to be added. :(

Comment: @pjustindaryll . . . Something is wrong with your data model if you are just adding new columns to a table.  **These should be stored in separate rows.**