# UNPIVOT - DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, db2, unpivot

I have data like below

```
ROW_ID    Col0           Col1    Col2    Col3    
1         05/22/2020      123     ABC     1
2         05/12/2020      DEF     1       2
3         06/13/2020      PRR     N1      4
```

I am looking for the output where data will transformed very little and then will be un-pivoted as shown below

```
ROW_ID  COLUMN_NAME  VALUE
1       Col0         05/22/2020
1       Drv_Col0     May-2020
1       Col1         123
1       Col2         ABC
1       Col3         1
1       Sum_Col3     3
2       Col0         05/12/2020
2       Drv_Col0     May-2020
2       Col1         DEF
2       Col2         1
2       Col3         2
2       Sum_Col3     3
3       Col0         06/13/2020
3       Drv_Col0     Jun-2020
3       Col1         PRR
3       Col2         N1
3       Col3         4
3       Sum_Col3     4
```

Comment: Take a look at the "standard SQL unpivot" answer here [Unpivot with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join.  Assuming that the columns all have the same type:

```
select t.row_id, v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values ('Col0', col0),
             ('Drv_Col0', to_char(col0, 'MON-YYYY'),
             ('Col1', col1),
             ('Col2', col2),
             ('Col3', col3),
             ('Sum_Col3', ???)
     ) v(column_name, value);
```

Note:  You may need to cast the columns so they are all strings.

The question does not specify how `sum_col3` is defined and the definition is not obvious.  But some expression can go there.

Comment: How you are handling the SUM for Col3

Comment: @KoushikChandra . . . I didn't even see it in the question.  That said, the question is no clear on how it is defined, so I don't know what the expression is.

Comment: I am getting error - data type of corresponding columns are not compatible. For my example Col0 is DATE and Col3 is BIGINT

Comment: @KoushikChandra . . . The answer specifies that you may need to cast the values to a common type, such as a string.  Your question doesn't specify what the types are, so you can figure out what the right method is to convert to a string.