# SQL Multiple Column Names to Single Column 'Type'

Tags: sql, sql-server

So column names of a table I imported needs to be converted to a 'Type' column. I did it with UNION though I was reading that is not the proper way to do things RE: PIVOT and UNPIVOT and the table is much larger + different subject matter.

What is the best way to do this?

Current implementation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAKE, 'AUTOMOBILE' as TYPE,  AUTOMOBILE AS MODEL
FROM VEHICLE
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT MAKE, 'MOTORCYCLE' as TYPE, MOTORCYLE AS MODEL
FROM VEHICLE
```

INPUT:

| MAKE | AUTOMOBILE | MOTORCYCLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 340I | null |
| BMW | 540I | null |
| BMW | null | M1000RR |

DESIRED OUTPUT:

| MAKE | TYPE | MODEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | AUTOMOBILE | 340I |
| BMW | AUTOMOBILE | 540I |
| BMW | MOTORCYCLE | M1000RR |

Thanks

Comment: Is this not just a `CASE`? `Type = CASE WHEN AUTOMOBILE IS NOT NULL THEN ...` and `Model = ISNULL(AUTOMOBILE, MOTORCYCLE)`

Comment: Or normalize your table if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here: [Unpivot with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.MAKE, U.TYPE, U.MODEL
FROM VEHICLE
UNPIVOT
(
     MODEL
     FOR TYPE IN (AUTOMOBILE, MOTORCYCLE)
) U
ORDER BY U.MAKE
```