# Sum columns with the same prefix in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think it's a really basic question, but I couldn't find the answer how to do it in SQL Server.
I have a table:

| ID | Pref_01 | Pref_02 | ... | Pref_40 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 5 | 2 | ... | 7 |
| 02 | 6 | 7 | ... | 5 |

I want my output to contain two columns: ID, Sum_pref with the sum of columns which names stars with "pref". I know how to do it in R or SQL in SAS but now I have to do it in SQL Server and I'm stuck. I will be greatful for any help.

Comment: One method would be to unpivot your data, and then `SUM` it. The other would be to simply use basic addition: `Pref01 + Pref02 + ... + Pref_40`. I suspect that what you actually have is a denormalised design here.

Comment: The basic addition is not a solution. In original data i have many more columns and different prefixes so it would be to many work. I'm looking for something like sum(of Prefix:) in SAS

Comment: There is no such feature. If you want to use a `SUM` you'll need to unpivot your data first and then `SUM` the column.

Comment: That's bad :(. Could you provide an example how to do this using unpivot?

Comment: What's bad? And there's are lots, for example: [Unpivot with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055902/unpivot-with-column-name)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality to achieve what you need.

Notable points:

1. 1st `CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing columns for each row as XML.
2. 2nd `CROSS APPLY` is summarizing values where XML element names (and original column names) are matching a particular naming convention.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Pref_01 INT, Pref_02 INT, Pref_40 INT);
INSERT @tbl (Pref_01, Pref_02, Pref_40) VALUES
(5, 2, 7),
(6, 7, 5);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
   , [sum-columns-across-the-row]
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT x.value('sum(/root/*[contains(local-name(), "Pref_")]/text()) cast as xs:integer?', 'INT')) AS t2([sum-columns-across-the-row]);
```

**Output**

| id | Pref_01 | Pref_02 | Pref_40 | sum-columns-across-the-row |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 7 | 14 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 18 |